# error on .then (Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.)

Tags: ionic-framework

Im new to ionic angular, please help.

```js
this.socialSharing.shareViaInstagram('test test', newBase64).then((res) => {
  console.log("testvalue=====", res);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("error value ====", error);
});
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the `socialSharing` object or show us which plugin you are using?

Comment: import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';

Comment: Have you installed and imported the plugin correctly? You can edit your question to explain your problem to the world.

Comment: Im sure i have installed correctly

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

That's because it doesn't return a Promise.

```
shareViaInstagram: (message?: string, fileOrFileArray?: string | ArrayLike<string>, successCallback?: SocialSharingSuccessCallback<never>, errorCallback?: SocialSharingErrorCallback) => void
```

see https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/091df268b17b6092cb4224ff9bc65f87b2e3419d/types/index.d.ts#L34

You need to do instead:

```
const onSuccess = () => console.log("testvalue=====", res);
const onError = (error) => console.log("error value ====", error);

this.socialSharing.shareViaInstagram('test test', newBase64, onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: what do you mean it wont reply a promise

Comment: @NewLimSiangChing if the docs are referring to the correct plugin repository, then we can see that `shareViaInstagram` returns a void, but accept success and error as callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `then` to `subscribe`:

```
this.socialSharing.shareViaInstagram('test test', newBase64).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("testvalue=====", res);
} ,error => {
      console.log(error);
};
```

Comment: i've tested on my phone , it's fine . What platform do you use to test ?

Answer (score 0):

> import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';

#### Import

You didn't import the package correctly. Add `ngx` at the end.

```js
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
```

#### Share to Instagram functionality

Share directly to Instagram

```js
shareViaInstagram(message: string, image: string): Promise<any> {
  return;
}
```

Or share via App name

```js
shareVia(
    appName: string, // <-- instagram
    message: string,
    subject?: string,
    image?: string,
    url?: string
  ): Promise<any> {
    return;
  }
```

You can also check if you can share to Instagram, look in the provided documentation for the functionality.

Documentation: 
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/social-sharing/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have imported the module or not

In my case:

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx'
```